# Anyway for setting Telegram Webhook without setting up https connection

Tags: http, ssl, https, webhooks, telegram-bot

I want to setup `Telegram` `Webhook` but I don't have `https` URL, I don't want to deal with ssl certificates either.

Can I solve this problem by using https URL or without setting `https` certificate up?

Telegram webhook desc: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook

Answer (score 18):

`https` is mandatory but it doesn't mean you MUST set it up completely. You can use more more simple ways, let me explain:

You can connect your localhost server on your own PC or mac or linux machine, to telegram severs without setting any SSL Certificates.
With using ["ngrok.com Secure tunnels"](https://ngrok.com) you will have a https address that is mandatory for dealing with `webhooks` but no need to setup any SSL. [image]

All steps you need (in PC):

> 1- Download ngrok.exe
>
> 2- Run in command line : "ngrok http 8888"
>
> 3- It is ready Now!

very simple,is not it

After running ngrok.exe it shows you somthing like: "https://abcd1234.ngrok.io"
This is your temporary https that you can use as webhook. It is valid and belong to your bot until you close `ngrok.exe`( I even standby my computer without closing app and it remains for me-excellent)
[image]

Additionally with this app i have access to all messages that Telegram send to my bot and my bot api outputs (not include my sent message) as JSON show. You can access to these panel via `http://localhost.com:4040` . This is a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have two options to get updates from telegram:

1. Webhook, this method works over ssl only (yes, I agree with Tom - let's encrypt is awesome)
2. getUpdates method, that work using long polling, this method does not require ssl. More info in API documentation: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

Answer (score 2):

You can't without a proper certificate, but it's now really easy to get one (and for free) : https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: I have my webhook setup using a self-signed cert but am looking into using a Let's Encrypt cert on my server. For some reason telegram keeps giving me Verification_Failed errors but browsers are fine with it. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Did you test your https entry point with ssllabs.com ? Does it says something about "chain issues" ? If yes, your intermediate certificate is incorrect in the config.

Comment: I did check it with https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and there is no issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the Cloudflare Universal SSL to protect your endpoint with SSL. You don't have to deal with anything.