# Is necessary to have https for connecting laravel to telegram?

Tags: laravel

Is necessary to have https for send notification to telegram channel via laravel!?

And if you have any good source for this discussion, please introduce me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it necessary to have https for [blank]? Yes. Since you can use https for free (lets encrypt) in almost all use cases there is no good reason not to use it. My mindset regarding security is "do it unless there is a reason not to" and in the case of https there is never a case not to.

Comment: @milo526 thank you vert much. And do you have any source for this(send notification from laravel to telegra channel) ??

Comment: Read the first answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38634866/5811368

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović thank you kindly